# Passing function as an argument in goroutine

Tags: function, go, arguments, goroutine

```
import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func WithRecover(r func()) {
    r()
}

func printRewardAmount(rewardAmount int) {
    fmt.Println(rewardAmount)
}

func main() {
    var rewardAmount int
    rewardAmount = 1
    go WithRecover(func() { printRewardAmount(rewardAmount) })
        if true {
        rewardAmount = 2
        }
    time.Sleep(100 * time.Millisecond)
}
```

As we are passing rewardAmount as a value, output should be 1. But I'm getting 2 sometimes, could someone explain me why ?

Comment: Your code accesses `rewardAmount` from multiple goroutines, where one of the access is a write. This is a data race. You must synchronize access to `rewardAmount`.

Comment: But we are passing rewardAmount as a value not as a reference

Comment: When you pass it, you have to _read_ its value to know what to pass. And the `main` goroutine _writes_ it.

Comment: when does the goroutine reads the value on creation or execution ?
Cause goroutine creation will happen before setting the value to 2

Comment: It's read during the execution of the goroutine. Things would be different if you wrote `go printRewardAmount(rewardAmount)` instead; then there would be no race.

Comment: Only arguments to the function launched as a goroutine are evaluated before actually launching it. Everything inside the function body will be executed concurrently. And no, you don't have guarantee which one happens first, they run _concurrently_.  Please watch this video if you're not clear what it means: [Concurrency is not parallelism](https://go.dev/blog/waza-talk)

Answer (score 2):

```golang
go WithRecover(func() { printRewardAmount(rewardAmount) })
```

In the above code you're just passing the value of `rewardAmount` to `printRewardAmount()` function only, not to the go routine. Hence the scope of  `rewardAmount` is still outside of the go routine(inside `main()`). So the output can be either 1 or 2 based on the order of execution of the go routine.

Just see the address of `rewardAmount` by replacing `main()` with the following

```golang
func main() {
    var rewardAmount int
    rewardAmount = 1
    fmt.Println("address of rewardAmount in main:", &rewardAmount)
    go WithRecover(func() {
        fmt.Println("address of rewardAmount inside go routine:", &rewardAmount)
        printRewardAmount(rewardAmount)
    })
    if true {
        rewardAmount = 2
    }
    time.Sleep(100 * time.Millisecond)
}
```

[full code in playground](https://go.dev/play/p/Ay8RjU4W63Y)

But when you do the following, you're actually copying and passing the value of `rewardAmount` to the go routine. Hence the output will be 1 always.

```golang
func main() {
    var rewardAmount int
    rewardAmount = 1
    fmt.Println("address of rewardAmount in main:", &rewardAmount)
    go func(rewardAmount int) {
        fmt.Println("address of rewardAmount inside go routine:", &rewardAmount)
        WithRecover(func() {
            printRewardAmount(rewardAmount)
        })
    }(rewardAmount)
    if true {
        rewardAmount = 2
    }
    time.Sleep(100 * time.Millisecond)
}
```

[full code in playground](https://go.dev/play/p/m2oLCXJyuTK)